# Swiper.js scroll event issue with laptop's trackpad

Tags: javascript, swiper.js, trackpad

I am currently creating a view where a different image loads when a vertical scroll event occurs. Other parts are implemented well, but when scrolling with the laptop's trackpad, I am experiencing an issue where several pages are skipped at a time. Does anyone know the cause or solution?

When I scroll through the trackpad, I want the screen to go over one page at a time with results such as mousewheel and mobile touch events

Comment: This might rather have a hardware-specific cause. From my experience, track pads often are set to a higher scroll rate than mouse wheels etc. Possibly, you can find the settings for your track pad in your system settings and adapt them. I think, there's nothing you can change in your JS code as e. g. mouse wheel and track pad scrolling produce the same events processed by your code and you can't differentiate the origin.